# react-native-document-picker: Type error-->undefined document picker while calling document picker.show in react native 0.61.2

Tags: react-native

[image]

When upgraded to react-native 0.61.2 this issue came.
I did,
Removed apk from mobile and
automatically linking using

```
react-native link
```

then

```
react-native run-android
```

but the issue exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In new version of **react-native-document-picker@3.2.4**.  They changed method names earlier versions of document picker we import `DocumentPicker` and `DocumentPickerUtil` both methods, but in new version of this npm we will import only one method `DocumentPicker`.

Replace this

> import { DocumentPicker, DocumentPickerUtil } from "react-native-document-picker";

To this

> import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker';

Comment: this worked for me. 

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your react-native version to 0.61.0. The recent version (0.61.2) is not yet stable with react-native-document-picker and expo-document-picker.

Comment: I have upgraded all libraries with this version. Downgrading is a huge task. The issue is the document picker changed the total way of implementation, updated it and the issue is fixed.